# Does a backing property created for only public properties?

Tags: android, kotlin, field

First of all I read the link:
[Backing Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)

I am not sure I understand from the link, although I saw an example:

[Backing Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties)

will a backing field be created for a non public property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with public/private.

A backing field is always created unless there is a custom getter (and setter for `var`) and it (neither of them) uses `field`. A backing field is the only way the value of a property can be stored, regardless of whether it is public. When neither the getter nor setter references `field`, only then it will not be generated.

In that backing properties example (duplicated below), the `_table` property has a backing field because it is using the default property implementation. The `table` property has no backing field because it doesn't use one in its getter.

```
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null
public val table: Map<String, Int>
    get() {
        if (_table == null) {
            _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
        }
        return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
    }
```